# ckeditor dont replace when i get a data with javascript xmlhttp

Tags: javascript, php, xmlhttprequest, ckeditor, frame

i'm looking to find a solution about my problem...
i have some page, index - /folder/: showpage - /ckeditor/ 
in index page i have a bit code... i cant think to can share....
anyway, to index page i have a function in javascript that call from xmlhttp my /folder/showpage, now i show it in in the same page of index, and my textare not change.

```
function ticketDetails(id){
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
        // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
        xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
    } else { // code for IE6, IE5
        xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function() {
        if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200) {
            document.getElementById("yourTicket").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
        }
    }
    xmlhttp.open("POST","./support/yourTicket.php",true);
    xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    xmlhttp.send('ticketid='+id);
}
```

this function call the frame, now in yourTicket.php my textare code...

```
<form method="post" name="modulo" id="modulo">Answer<br/>
<textarea style="margin: 4px;width: 850px;" rows="5" cols="70" name="answer" 
id="answer" onblur="javascript:checkIns(event, 'message');"></textarea><br />
<input  style="float:right;margin-right: 18px;margin-top: 30px;" type="button" id="submit" value="Answer" onclick="javascript:answer('<? echo $ticketID;?>');"/>

</form>
```

i test with insert code for replace to index page, and dont working, because my textarea=answer dont exist, in yourTicket.php page i insert this code

```
<script type="text/javascript">CKEDITOR.replace('answer');</script>
```

not working, and no error....
in my index page i have script code for include cketidor and for my first textare working(in index page location)...

sorry for but english, but i really not know what i can do... thanks all